# Chunking a directory and applying image blending using PIL. Can't save images correctly with Python

Tags: python, image, save, python-imaging-library, blend

Sorry for the title... So the goal of this script is to take a folder full on images that are listed in a particular order. Then it chunks the images into groups of 3. From there it takes the 3 images and blends them together using PIL. Now the issue that I have is that the code below does a great job of doing what I want. I can show `imgbld2` it'll create 4 images in a temporary folder.

Now my problem is that when I go to save the images using `imgbld2.save()`it will only save the first created image into 4 image files, instead of 4 created images into 4 separate files.

I can fix this issue by pointing another script to retrieve the images from the temp folder by using `glob.glob()`. But that would require me to make sure to run the script on a freshly restarted computer but that seems to be too messy for my taste.

Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do? Or there a saving method that I'm missing?

Any help would be appreciated, here is the code:

```
from PIL import Image
import os.path
import glob

#Lists Directory
Dir = os.listdir('/path/to/Directory/of/Images')
#Glob all jpgs
im = glob.glob( '/path/to/Directory/of/Images/*.jpg')

#sort jpg according to name
imsort = sorted(im)

def chunker(imsort,size = 3):
    for i in range(0, len(imsort), size):
        yield imsort[i:i + size]

print('what does it look like?')

for j in chunker(imsort):
    print(j)

    img1 = Image.open(j[0])
    img2 = Image.open(j[1])
    img3 = Image.open(j[2])

    imgbld1 = Image.blend(img1, img2, 0.3)
    imgbld2 = Image.blend(imgbld1, img3, 0.3)

    imgbld2.show()
    imgbld2.save('path/to/new/folder/' + 'blended'  , 'JPEG')
```

Comment: Where are you calling `save()`?

Comment: @Cfreak Hey I updated the code. save is sent to a new folder with jpeg as its filetype.